# C#: how can I add a list of values into a MySQL WHERE IN clause

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a list of values and want to use it in a query but how can I add each value with quotes into mysql where clause.

```
List <string> customerlist = new List<string>();
sql =  SELECT * FROM customerlist WHERE custid IN customerlist
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

I need to add quotes around them. Can you advice how I can do that please?

Comment: What database access technology are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Select` to add quotes and `Join` to create a comma-separated list:

```
var clause = String.Join("," , customerlist.Select(s => "'" + s + "'"));
```

Note that any strings with single quotes within them would cause syntax issues. If that's the case (or if you want to be on the safe side), then just escape them when projecting:

```
var escaped = customerlist.Select(s => "'" + s.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
var clause = String.Join("," , escaped));
```

Also note that DB frameworks like Entity Framework have methods where you can supply a list of values and the equivalent SQL will be generated for you.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked. I am using ADO.NET to connect to the MYSQL db. I just needed to use the first line example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join them

```
string.Join(',', customerList.Select(x => "'" + x "'").ToArray());
```

This gives you 'Clair', 'Alex', 'Bob'

Answer (score 0):

Here a suggestion without using LINQ:

```
private void Example()
{
    List<string> customerlist = new List<string>();
    customerlist.Add("co111");
    customerlist.Add("co112");
    customerlist.Add("co114");

    // string in SQL needs "'"
    ConvertToSqlString(ref customerlist);
    // use String.Join() to seperate with ","
    var sql = @"SELECT * FROM customerlist 
                WHERE custid IN (" + String.Join(",",customerlist) + ")";
}

private void ConvertToSqlString(ref List<string> lst)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<lst.Count;i++)
    {
        lst[i] = "'" + lst[i] + "'";
    }
}
```